# how to get attributes of a multidimensional json obj

Tags: php, json

Im working on creating a burn down chart with data from jira dashboard. Using curl in php, i got a json object (as shown below) which i stored as $res. This is multidimentional and as im new to JSON, im struggling to extract attributes like changes, statisticField, startTime, endTime etc into my php code, even after referring to many answers as i find this too nested. May I know how to extract these into php variables?

My json obj is:

```
    {
    changes: {
    1435802352000: [
    {
    key: "PDM-6680",
    column: {
    notDone: true,
    newStatus: "1"
    }
    }
    ],

    1465224095000: [
    {
    key: "PDM-7104",
    added: true
    },
    {
    key: "PDM-7114",
    added: true
    }
    ],

    1466160360000: [
    {
    key: "PDM-12865",
    timeC: {
    oldEstimate: 0,
    newEstimate: 0,
    changeDate: 1466160360000
    },
    column: {
    notDone: false,
    done: true,
    newStatus: "6"
    }
    }
    ],
    1466160537000: [
    {
    key: "PDM-12865",
    timeC: {
    oldEstimate: 0,
    newEstimate: 0,
    changeDate: 1466160537000
    }
    }
    ],


    startTime: 1465387620000,
    endTime: 1466185620000,
    completeTime: 1466434989792,
    now: 1466442135123,
    statisticField: {
    typeId: "field",
    fieldId: "timeestimate",
    id: "field_timeestimate",
    name: "Remaining Time Estimate",
    isValid: true,
    isEnabled: true,
    renderer: "duration"
    },
    issueToParentKeys: {
    PDM-12815: null,
    PDM-12417: null,
    PDM-12865: "PDM-10065",
    PDM-12864: "PDM-10065",
    PDM-6730: null,
    PDM-12861: "PDM-12420",
    PDM-12420: null,
    PDM-12860: "PDM-12420"
    },
    workRateData: {
    timezone: "Asia/Singapore",
    rates: [

    {
    start: 1466208000000,
    end: 1466380800000,
    rate: 0
    },
    {
    start: 1466380800000,
    end: 1466434989792,
    rate: 1
    }
    ]
    },
    openCloseChanges: {
    1466434989881: [
    {
    userDisplayNameHtml: "<a class="user-hover" rel="xxxx" id="_xxxx" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=xxxx">xxxx</a>",
    operation: "CLOSE"
    }
    ]
    },
    lastUserWhoClosedHtml: "<a class="user-hover" rel="xxxx" id="_xxxx" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=xxxx">xxxxxx</a>"
    }
```

and my php code(skipping curl part) is :

```
<?php

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$res= (array)json_decode($result);

$res= json_encode($res,true);
echo $res;


?>
```

Comment: print_r($res); what is the result of this

Comment: `$res= (array)json_decode($result);echo "<pre/>";print_r($res);` it will give you an array and fetching data from that will be very easy

Comment: The result was the same as above..

Comment: when i did echo gettype($res);  it said array. But i didnt know how to assign these attributes to php variables.

Comment: To get an array use `json_decode($result, true)`, NOT this `(array)json_decode($result);`.